# В response возвращается не корректные данные

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

Есть функция передающая логин и пароль на бэк, в ответ должна получать стату код, однако возвращается почему то логин, вместо статус-кода и соответственно функция не отрабатывает как надо. Никак не пойму в чем дело.

Фронт:

```
function fetchRequest(method: string, url: string, body: object = {}): Promise<any> {
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }

  const responsePromise = fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
    headers: headers,
    credentials: "same-origin"
  }).then((response) => {
    return response.status
  }, err => {
    console.log(err, "data wasn't wrote")
  })
  return responsePromise
}

export const login = (login: string, password: string, loginHandler: string, loginPageModelInstance: LoginPageModel) => {
  const user = {
    login: login,
    password: password
  }
  const loginPromise = fetchRequest("POST", loginHandler, user)
  loginPromise.then((response) => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      loginPageModelInstance.setLoginStatus(true)
      renderAdminPage(rootElement, loginPageModelInstance)
      return response
    }
  })
}
```

Бэк:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const user = req.body
  if (!fs.existsSync(dataPath)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dataPath)
  }
  if (!fs.existsSync(usersFilePath)) {
    fs.writeFileSync(usersFilePath, "[]")
  }
  const userFound = findUserByLogin(user.login)
  if (userFound && userFound.password === user.password) {
    const cookieAge = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    const authToken = generateAuthToken()
    authorisedUsers[authToken] = userFound.login
    res.cookie('auth-token', authToken, { maxAge: cookieAge, httpOnly: false })
    console.log("login successful")
    res.status(200)
  } else {
    console.log("user not found")
    res.status(401)
  }
})
```

Спасибо!

Comment: может быть запрос обрабатывается другим обработчиком?

Comment: `.then((response) => {
    return response.status` — вот тут вы возвращаете число, а потом почему-то проверяете `response.status` которого больше нет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen хорошее замечание, спасибо! Но все таки это не решает проблему :) Однако в response возвращается логин еще до проверки response.status

Comment: Я не вижу в вашем серверном обработчкие где отправляется ответ. `res.status` только выставляет статус, но не отправляет ответ

Comment: @AlexeyTen и снова отличное замечание :) Однако вновь не то

Comment: Так я всё таки не пойму где же у вас логин вместо кода.

Comment: `const loginPromise = fetchRequest("POST", loginHandler, user)
  loginPromise.then((response` - вот здесь возвращается логин `) => {
    if (response.status === 200) `

Comment: Не верю. `response.status` выше это всегда число, а ваш `loginPromise` возвращает либо его, либо `undefined`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, я это понимаю, но факт остается фактом :) если могу Вам прислать в какой то месенджер фото отладчика - могу сделать

Comment: Приложите его в вопрос

Comment: Так, я вообще в недоумении, но каким то образом проблема решилась. Спасибо, буду искать проблему дабы не повторялось

Comment: @AlexeyTen Нашел! Не перезапустил ноду, после исправления res.status. Спасибо, Алексей!